# NSMutableArray initialization

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, init

I'm very newby on Objective C. I've read a lot of topics related but couldn't get solution. 
I'm using a NSMutableArray, and alloc and init by the following mode:

```
events = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
```

Is it right? In this way, I can add objects to the array without problems, but when I iterate or to read, I got `SIGABRT: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. Attempting several modifications, the best I could get was another exception: `EXC_BAD_ADDRESS`. The line I'm using to read the array is:

```
Event *event = [events objectAtIndex:1];
```

Thanks in advance.

Junior

Comment: Hm. You are talking about `NSMutableArray` but do `NSMutableSet alloc`... ?

Answer (score 3):

you have said you are using NSMutableArrays, but then initialised a set, try using:

```
NSMutableArray *events = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

sets don't respond to objectAtIndex, because they are unordered. if you want an object out of a set, you can call anyObject on it. or you can use enumeration to go through all objects.
eg

```
id obj=[events anyObject];
```

or

```
for(id obj in events){
    NSLog(@"%@",obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's going on in between? Remember that arrays are zero-indexed; there may not be two elements in there. Try using the count method.

Answer (score 0):

```
events = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[events addObject:event1];
[events addObject:event2]

for (int i = 0; i < [events count]; i++) {
    Event *event = (Event)[events objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog("Event: %@", event);
    [event release];
}
```

Like this.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your question, please tick it as "correct". : )